# Read text in a file to check environment variables

Tags: python

I am trying to read in the contents of a text file, then use that to carry out a os.getenv check for certain settings. I am having trouble in making the text into a variable can you assist?

The code is

```
import os
for env_check in open('env_check.conf'):
  print env_check
  newenv = os.getenv('"'+env_check+'"')
  if newenv is None:
    print newenv, 'is not set'
  else:
    print 'Current Setting for ' + newenv
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the contents of `env_check.conf`?

Comment: a list of the environment variables I want to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print your environment variables in square brackets, you'll soon see that they have newlines appended (I'm assuming that newlines separate the list you mention in the comments, if you have a comma-separated list or some such then additional work is required).

You can remove these with [**`str.strip()`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.strip#str.strip) and then pass this variable directly into [**`os.getenv()`**](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.getenv). Then you can print them thus:

```
import os
for env_check in open('env_check.conf'):
    env_check = env_check.strip()
    print '[{}]'.format(env_check)
    newenv = os.getenv(env_check)
    if newenv is None:
        print env_check, 'is not set'
    else:
        print 'Current Setting for {}={}'.format(env_check, newenv)
```

Comment: I see. I would have assumed that you would have noticed this already since you had `print env_check` in your code.

Comment: No I must of missed that, I think I was missing the .strip. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`os.getenv()` works fine. My guess is that the quotes you add around the environment variable name should not be there. Replace

```
os.getenv('"'+env_check+'"')
```

with

```
os.getenv(env_check)
```

---

As @BluePeppers correctly points out you should also replace

```
print newenv, 'is not set'
```

with

```
print env_check, 'is not set'
```

Comment: I have tried that it just lists that they are not set.  It prints it then says None is not set

Comment: That's because you are doing `print newenv, 'is not set'`, which will always be None is not set. You want `print env_check, 'is not set'`

Comment: Thanks, it is still not getting the enviroment variable setting from the os.getenv, I know some of them are set

Comment: I can't tell from here what `env_check.conf` contains, for example. When faced with a problem like this the way to attack it is to simplify. Try this: `print os.getenv('PATH')`.

Comment: Yeah I should of printed the contents, it was a list of the settings I wanted to check.  I had tried them all manually, I wanted to get it to work via the file, so when new variables are created and checked I wouldn't have to edit the code each time.